# Open In Explorer using Javascript outside masterpage

Tags: javascript, open-with-explorer, core-js

The following code works like a charm when executed from an aspx using the sharepoint masterpage. However, I need it to work from an html file in a document library on the same site.

*e.g. Works when running from http://portal.dev/ (startpage)
Does not work running from http://portal.dev/documents/htmlpage.html*

```
CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', 'http://portal.dev/documents/', '_blank', 'http://portal.dev/');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bookmarklet (Favourite) with:

```
javascript:NavigateHttpFolder("http://portal.dev/documents","blank");
```

But this will only work in IE as it relies on ActiveX technology